# Revert media storage from db to file system

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-admin

I am using Magento 2.3.3, we have chosen database as our media storage medium, now I want to revert this setting to File System. I have implement this on staging server and it worked perfectly although I don't have any evidence whether the operation is completed or not, also I don't have any clue that how much time the process took but I have my media directory which is bumped upto 17gigs, I have few concerns before implementing this on production, I need help from the community.

1. How much time it may take on production, any rough idea?
2. How I will confirm that all the data has been moved?
3. How I will test that the new images are being uploaded to filesystem?
4. During the process on staging server, I have observed that the staging server speed gone down, additionally images were appearing and disappearing in loop, is this normal?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.